# How to access c# variable in javascript in selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the following code, I have a variable linkLocation which I want to access in my JavaScript code. It shows error "Linklocation is not defined". How I will access the variable in the JavaScript code ?

```
    IWebElement link = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("soemtext"));
    String linkLocation = link.GetAttribute("href");             
    Console.WriteLine(linkLocation);
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open(linkLocation, 'groupPage')");
```

Comment: C# is server side code, javascript is client side.  To get them to talk to each other you have to implement ClientScriptManager registration.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx

Comment: You are passing in the literal string of `linkLocation` as opposed to it's variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the last line to :

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("console.log('" + linkLocation + "'); window.open('" + linkLocation + "', 'groupPage')");
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

On the basis of my experience of how Selenium works in other languages, I'd expect something like this to work:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
    "window.open(arguments[0], 'groupPage')", new Object[] { linkLocation });
```

(I don't code in C#. Hopefully I don't have an obvious syntax error in the code above.)

The [`ExecuteScript` method](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm) takes an optional array of objects that are passed as arguments to the JavaScript code. On the browser side, what you passed to `ExecuteScript` is executed inside a function so the code above would be equivalent to:

```
function () {
    window.open(arguments[0], 'groupPage');
}
```

The kind of concatenation you show in your self-answer is generally unsafe. If double quotes appear in `linkLocation` (which is possible; in query parameters, for instance), the concatenated string will be invalid JavaScript code.

Comment: Great idea, I was able to pass an IWebElement method to my javascript using this method.